# Transfer eth with hex data via smart contract

Tags: solidity

I am trying to transfer a certain number of eth from my contract to another contract. However, aside from eth, I also need to transfer hexdata. Just like how it is done in metamask:

[image]

How do I do this with solidity? I could not find anything from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the low-level `call` member of `address` type ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#members-of-addresses)).

It takes the `value` as a property of the options object, and the argument represents the `data` field of the transaction.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Sender {
    Receiver receiver;

    constructor(address payable _receiver) {
        receiver = Receiver(_receiver);
    }

    function sendWithData() external payable {
        bytes memory sendData = abi.encode("hello");
        (bool success,) = address(receiver).call{value: msg.value}(sendData);
        require(success);
    }
}

contract Receiver {
    event Received(bytes, uint256);

    fallback(bytes calldata receivedData) external payable returns (bytes memory) {
        emit Received(receivedData, msg.value);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: This require(success) statement is necessary to prevent an attack right?

Comment: @user1506104 In this case it's not preventing an attack. I put it there just to validate if the receiver has really received or rejected the funds.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. I believe this was the source of the TheDao attack.

Comment: @user1506104 The infamous 2016 DAO hack was in fact possible because of a [reentrancy](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107) vulnerability in the code ([source article](https://hackingdistributed.com/2016/06/18/analysis-of-the-dao-exploit/)). One of the ways to protect against reentrancy is to set all storage variables first, and perform an external call as the last operation. Or another way is to set a flag value in storage first and then check its value (see [OpenZeppelin docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/security#ReentrancyGuard)).